# Where is GitHub Flavored Markdown (GFM) actually used in GitHub?

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages

This has been a mystery to me for a while, and for some reason Google didn't help me, so let me ask.

EDIT: ok, I understand the GFM is everywhere in GitHub, and why GFM style line break edit is not available?? Is it turned off? and I know the original MD rule. **What I'd like to confirm here is GFM line break rule.** Thank you.

**I like GFM very much especially for the straightfoward line break manner.
https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown
However, I have been never able to post my own Markdown with this line beak mode.**

For instance, I copied some syntax list MD to a new page of one of my wiki on GitHub.

https://github.com/kenokabe/kenokabe.github.io/wiki/MarkDownGFM

As you can confirm the MD source.

```
This is intended as a quick reference and showcase. 
For more complete info, see [John Gruber's original spec]
```

a single new line is applied; however, the result shown with no new line.

What do I miss? Where is GitHub Flavored Markdown (GFM) is actually used in GitHub?

*(Technical note: Markdown Here uses GFM line breaks, so there's no need to use MD's two-space line breaks.)*

It certainly says so, but I found this md uses 2 spaces br manner.

Comment: You might want to change the title of the question to reflect its new content.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Contrary to the other answers, GFM is *only* used where text is *only* entered through the GitHub website, not in README.md and not on GitHub Wikis.

From https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown (emphasis added)

> GitHub uses what we're calling "GitHub Flavored Markdown" (GFM) for
>   **messages**, **issues**, and **comments**.

The reasoning behind this is that README.md and Wikis are part of Git repositories, and therefore can be cloned outside of the site, where one would reasonably expect (standard) Markdown rather than GFM.

For more on GitHub's rationale, see https://github.com/github/markup/issues/208#issuecomment-24927799

**Edit:**

Syntax highlighting (Pygments) is separate from GFM, in that, GFM employs syntax highlighting, however the presence of syntax highlighting does not entail GFM, hence why GitHub Pages will use standard Markdown line-breaks: it uses Pygments, but not GFM.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought and wanted to confirm. In fact, I had planned to make some page like https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook for output for my own, but found it's hard to Edit with non-GFM line break, so. I end up with developing my own Content Management System.

Answer (score 0):

It's used when you display your README.md file on your repository front page, [for example](https://github.com/CodieCodemonkey/PyCog#pycog).   Also, when you add comments it's GFM.

Comment: It is also used for `Github Pages` and can be interpreted with `Jekyll` and translated to html. WAY nicer than writing straight html, IMO.

Comment: https://github.com/kenokabe/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/master/README.md This is some of my README.md and I just tried Hello/nWorld in the beginning. No line break, I see. What do I miss??

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey yeah def, starting to even be used off the site too, its nice!

Comment: @KenOKABE, You need two newlines to break a paragraph.  Markdown will assume that it can format sequential lines into a single paragraph unless that conflicts with other markdown rules.  For example, `Hello World` followed on the next line with `=========` will not assume the `==========` is part of the same paragraph, it will use the heading rule.

Comment: I know that  @Codie CodeMonkey, I am talking about GFM line breaks system, not legacy MD one.. What I like most on GFM is it doesn't require 2 space at the end of the line to get line break. What do I miss??

Comment: @KenOKABE, Ok, I get your point, I don't know why it isn't respecting the rule they documented here: https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown#newlines.  But let me point out the question you posted wasn't that, it was where GitHub uses markdown, which several people have answered.

Comment: Well, what obvious to me is the line break rule of GFM; so finding it's not applied, I simply thought GFM is not used from the first place. That is why I misunderstood the situation and title goes like that.

Comment: @KenOKABE, Yeah, I can understand that, and it's frustrating.  I wonder if maybe GFM doesn't do it for just the first line?

Comment: No. It simply like legacy MD. and my problem is I use GFM line break style in local environment and my new blog. At first, I thought I also could post the MD to github, but for this reason. The layout doesn't match.

Answer (score -1):

github flavored markdown is used on:

- your repo's readme file
- any .md files in your repo
- issues
- wikis & pages

and minimally on comments (commit, pull requests, etc)

a note about issues: it seems like it uses a limited version of GFM than on wiki pages or readme files.

Comment: Thank you @xero , do you have any idea why GFM specific line break style is not applied to them?

Comment: np. no, im not really sure. for comments i assume it's for the same reasons why they dont allow multi-line comments here. it's ok in the answer context, but not the comment context.