# How to insert a line break <br> in markdown

Tags: markdown

I'm trying to create a Markdown file with some paragraphs containing both a link and a line of text on the next line. The problem I've encountered is that when I make a new line after the link, it is rendered with a separate `<p>` tag.

My Markdown is the following:

```
[Name of link](url)

My line of text
```

Which is rendered to the following HTML:

```
<p>
   <a href="url">Name of link</a>
</p>
<p>My line of text</p>
```

Instead I want it to render like so:

```
<p>
    <a href="url">Name of link</a><br>  // not necessarily with a <br> tag but on a separate line
    My line of text
</p>
```

I've also tried using a single line break in the Markdown:

```
[Name of link](url)
My line of text
```

But then both the link and the text is rendered on the same line, but without a line break.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: try adding 2 spaces after `[Name of link](url)<space><space>`

Comment: https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#hard-line-breaks - but whether *your* markdown implementation support this, is unknown

Answer (score 360, accepted):

Try adding 2 spaces (or a backslash `\`) after the first line:

```
[Name of link](url)
My line of text\
```

Visually:

```
[Name of link](url)<space><space>
My line of text\
```

Output:

```
<p><a href="url">Name of link</a><br>
My line of text<br></p>
```

Alternatively you can place a `<br>` directly into the text. It is valid in Markdown.

Comment: I'm so glad I found this answer. Is there an official Markdown documentation with information like this included?

Comment: This is great, but with one small issue - having an editor set to remove excess whitespace ;)

Comment: @TimMalone FWIW, some editors (well, UltraEdit at least) support settings on a per-filetype basis, possibly you could disable the trimming for `.md` files.

Comment: Adding a backslash at the end of the line does the same.

Comment: Do you know why adding 2 spaces or a `\\` fixes it?

Comment: @Artur didn't know. they probably added it due to the issues with editors that trim trailing spaces.

Comment: This doesnt work with bitbuckets markdown editor. Nor does `<br/>`

Comment: This is cool, but in visual studio code i can't filter trim trailing whitespace by extension. So, i can't disable trim whitespace feature only for markdown. Nice but i prefer using the `<br>` tag.

Answer (score 49):

I know this post is about adding a single line break but I thought I would mention that you can create **multiple line breaks** with the backslash (`\`) character:

```
Hello
\
\
\
World!
```

This would result in 3 new lines after "Hello". To clarify, that would mean 2 empty lines *between* "Hello" and "World!". It would display like this:

---

Hello

World!

---

Personally I find this cleaner for a large number of line breaks compared to using `<br>`.

Note that backslashes are [not recommended for compatibility reasons](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#line-break-best-practices). So this **may not be supported by your Markdown parser** but it's handy when it is.

Comment: This is the only solution that I've tried that works in RichText component of Strapi.

Answer (score 37):

Combining answers from multiple sources, there are mainly 3 ways to add a line break in Markdown:

### 1. Backslash (`\`)

Add a backslash at the end of a line like this:

| Markdown Input | HTML Output | HTML Preview |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ``` Test line\ Test line 2 ``` | ``` <p>Test line</p><br> <p>Test Line 2</p> ``` | Test line Test line 2 |

### 2. HTML `<br>` tag

Lot of HTML Tags are directly supported in markdown. Add a HTML `<br>` or ` tag at the end of a line like this:

| Markdown Input | HTML Output | HTML Preview |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ``` Test line<br> Test line 2 ``` | ``` <p>Test line</p><br> <p>Test Line 2</p> ``` | Test line Test line 2 |

### 3. **Two spaces**

Add 2 spaces at the end of a line like this:

| Markdown Input | HTML Output | HTML Preview |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ``` Test line Test line 2 ``` | ``` <p>Test line</p><br> <p>Test Line 2</p> ``` | Test line Test line 2 |

**Option3.2** for whitespace - if you would like to be able to see the spaces while editing markdown source, add `\s` instead of whitespace( )

**Note: Option3.2 doesn't seem to work properly, but this is [documented in the markdown guide](https://markdown-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#line-return)**

```
Test line\s\s
Test line 2
```

Comment: I prefer Option1 (backslash) & Option2 (HTML `<br>`), since the backslash & `<br>` characters are clearly visible in the source format as well

Comment: A simple HTML`<br>` did work in storybook, thanks for taking your time to list this option.

Answer (score 26):

After a long search, I found this solution:

```
\
&nbsp;
\
&nbsp;
```

This will produce:

<br>
<br>

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Visual Studio code (on MacOS) (with MD lint checks) accepted only this solution. Thanks. What does nbsp mean..

Comment: None of the other options worked in the UI I was using, but this did. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a new line worked for me if you're to store the markdown in a JavaScript variable. like so

```
let markdown = `
    1. Apple
    2. Mango
     this is juicy
    3. Orange
`
```

Comment: This is working because you prefixed every line with four spaces which creates a preformatted section.  So I guess that is one way to do it.