# Github: Emphasise a single letter with markdown

Tags: github, markdown

I would like to emphasise several single letters at the beginning of a word to highlight the letters used for an abbreviation. Here's an example in markdown:

```
*SO* stands for *S*tack *O*verflow
```

But instead of the expected output (note the slanted first letters S and  O) of:

*SO* stands for *S*tack *O*verflow

on Github the output looks like:

*SO* stands for *S*tack *O*verflow.

Any ideas why is it not emphasised on Github? Does this relate to the [different markdown implementations](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/faq.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas why is it not emphasised on Github?

This looks to be on purpose. This limit is hinted in their **[documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/#multiple-underscores-in-words)**.

Note: The documentation deals with underscores (_), which are similar to stars (*) in markdown

Indeed, the following is not processed by GitHub

- *H*yper*t*ext *T*ransfer *P*rotocol

> Does this relate to the different markdown implementations?

Well, at least it *is* documented. Keep in mind that is rightfully named "Github *Flavoured* Markdown" ;-)

Comment: OK, that is good to know. Thanks for linking to the github documentation

Comment: After checking the documentation I also found that [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21272554/1498309) stating that GFM is used for "issues, comments, and pull requests". Nothing about commit like a `readme.md`.